# Atualizo o index.html e excluo arquivos, mas o github não atualiza

Tags: git, github

Eu iniciei um projeto no GitHub (estou começando agora com ele), e tava tudo funcionando perfeitamente. De uma hora pra outra, ele parou de atualizar. Eu, dentro do próprio site do GitHub, excluo arquivos, mudo o conteúdo da index.html e nada de ele atualizar, quando abro o link do projeto.

[Projeto atualizado](http://github.com/danielbonifacio/danielbonifacio.github.com)

[Página do projeto](http://danielbonifacio.github.io/)

Será que vou ter que excluir esse repositório e refazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**O possível erro**

Cheque o horário dos seus posts com o fuso horário do site do Github,pois este é um erro muito comum em que é reportado já que quando se vai postar algo no Github há está diferença de fuso horário fazendo com que o usuário tenha que esperar o tempo de diferença entre os fuso horários para poder aparecer a atualização de seus posts.

**Como consertar**

Olhando mais a fundo,descobri que o UTC deles é do Horário do Pacifico(UTC-8) aonde fica os servidores deles ou seja a diferença deles para o horário do Brasil é de 5 horas.

**Afinal o que é UTC ?**

> A hora UTC, como podemos observar, é a hora de referencia do Meridiano de Greenwich, que cruza o Reino Unido, onde em especial, localiza-se um famoso observatório - The Royal Observatory, localizado no Greenwich Park - existente desde 1884. Esta é portanto, a referencia de horário utilizado no mundo inteiro.
>
> Segue padrões do ISO - 6709 para poder definir o UTC de cada lugar.

**Mas o que é ISO - 6709 ?**

> ISO - 6709 é uma representação padrão da localização de ponto geográfico por coordenadas e é o padrão internacional para a representação de latitude, longitude e altitude para locais de pontos geográficos.

**Ajustar fuso horário**

Você pode tentar fazer esta diferença para igualar os horários,adicione nos headers enquanto fazendo o post,o seguinte :

```
curl -H "Time-Zone: America/Sao_Paulo" -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/github/linguist/contents/new_file.md
```

Esta parte do código `"Time-Zone: America/São Paulo"` irá fazer com que pegue o horário de Brasília(UCT - 3) e sincronize com os seus posts.

OBS : Caso esteja em outros lugares fora do estado de SP,lhe sugiro a dar uma olhada nesta lista então e recolocar conforme o seu lugar :

```
    America/Fortaleza - MA,PI,CE,RN,PB
    America/Araguaina - Tocantins
    America/Cuiaba - Mato Grosso
    America/Campo_Grande - Mato Grosso do Sul
    America/Belem - Pará,Amapa
    America/Porto_Velho - Rondonia
```

Há no máximo 556 zonas que seguem o UTC,tome cuidado ao fazer as devidas mudanças e sempre procure UTC que siga padrões do `ISO 6709`.

**E se não foi ? Então...paciência**

Espere um tempo para ver se atualiza as informações,mais para ser preciso,esta diferença de fuso horário(5 horas).

**Artigos/Documentações para encontrar soluções para diversos outros problemas :**

https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds/

https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/3vihrq/help_updating_my_github_pages/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422279/github-pages-are-not-updating

**Documentações para melhores informações**

Dê uma olhada nas seguintes documentações,para melhor entendimento :

https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-03-04-timezone-handling-changes/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Ótima resposta, amigo. Informações muito úteis. No meu caso, o problema estava ocorrendo com o Visual Studio Code. Percebi que, enquanto eu utilizava ele pra subir os arquivos pro GitHub, sempre ocorria um bug ao importar uma pasta, e ele não fazia mais push dos arquivos. Usando a ferramenta de controle do próprio GitHub, em um repositório novo, consegui resolver os problemas.